# facebook oauth error python login

Tags: facebook, facebook-access-token, facebook-oauth, facebook-authentication

HI i am using facebook oauth to get access token .below are my settings for app:

```
under APPS DOMAIN :
www.testio.online

under Site URL:
https:// www.testio.online/

under Valid OAuth redirect URIs:
https://www.testio.online/fb/login/ ,  https://test.online/
```

but still i am getting error :

```
"Unable to Load URL: The domain of the URL is not included in this application domain. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your application to plot Domain Applications in your application settings."
"Code": 191,
```

why is this error? how can i debug it ?

Comment: Where are you getting this error? What URL are you on at that moment?

Comment: @CBroe i am at `https://www.testio.online/fb/login/?code=AQDK-TJ8GS-cxhDlB2FsopVe5lQatzrYvtJtDpGdWcMO8tXGGHaZQWCS44G9wJWxT3viqVETRCEMUy0xyEgWceadghSfh2PRKflQqGNShaGHGFsh22H9PbI0f3Q9`

Comment: Please double-check that you are using the right app id everywhere in your code.

Comment: @CBroe yup i checked it i am using right id and secret .when i was working with localhost it working fine but now it just gives this error.and i checked app id and secret are not changed

Comment: @CBroe any idea what is causing the error?